# C# Error: "The name '..' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is driving me insane. I want to do something simple but have no idea because I am an absolute beginner. I want to take whats in the text boxes, and put them into 1 label, then make that label visible. I keep getting this error no matter what I try, "The name 'submittedData' does not exist in this context.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    submittedData.Text = name.Text + " " + email.Text + " " + phone.Text;
    submittedData.Visible = true;
}
}
```

And the aspx:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css"></link>

<title>Coding Club</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>Coding club registration form</h1>

        <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="phone">Your Phone:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="phone" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="submit_Click" />

        <asp:Button ID="clear" runat="server" Text="Clear Form" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="submittedData" runat="server"></label>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have an id on the last label, which seems to be the one you are targeting. You have a 'for' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `id` attribute on label element in aspx file

```
<label id="submittedData" runat="server"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like below:

```
<asp:Label id="submittedData" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Or asp:literal.

As your current label isnt a asp server control, you maynot set it via the label for thing.

Your underlying html will still generate 
`<label for>` tag.

Also I notice you have used:

```
<label for="name"> next to your text input box.
```

You can use `<asp:Label id=“labelName” AssociatedControlId=“name” runat=“server”>`

This way if you click on label, your textbox will get focus